Green "Play" Buttons on Manhattan Google Map
I see the color coding on the Google Maps display of Manahattan for areas of interest,  hospitals,  natural preserved areas,  etc. but what do the little green arrows that look like the play button shape   stand for? What do the little red areas attached that look like hallways stand for? Those aren't explained by the simple color coding system.


Maps Transit Layer

Both the symbol  and the red highlighted areas are part of the Google Maps Transit layer.
Access points to the underground stations are marked on zoomed out maps with  which changes to  when zoomed in.
 
The red highlighted area within which the entrance symbols are located shows the outline of the underground subway station including entrances and underground access tunnels and walkways.

